# Why can't I answer a protected question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, answering-questions, protected-questions

I came across [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48755/how-to-root-the-lg-optimus-2-as680) and was going to post an answer to help them root their phone since I recently did a similar phone, but it says it's protected. OK, I get that but what I don't is that it says you need 10 rep to post an answer. My reputation is sufficient for this, why can't I post an answer? It makes no sense to me so can anyone explain?

Answer (score 7):

The +100 rep association bonus is not counted in the protection algorithm. The post notice states (emphasis added):

> To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation *on this site*.

and the "on this site" part is actually quite literal, though not entirely clear. Therefore, looking at your rep history, you've got +100 for the association bonus and +5 for an upvote on one of your questions. That nets you 5 rep from your activities on this site, which is still shy of the 10 needed.

There is also a more detailed explanation of the "protected" status on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question), for reference.

In this specific case, the view count of the question is pretty low, so I'm going to remove the protection. It looks like it was applied because it picked up a bunch of non-answers within the first 24 hours, but then the views petered off after that.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks. I was under the impression the association bonus was granted to overcome such limits by transferring the trusted status of the person, this literal limitation seems to be counterproductive to that, but at least now I know what's going on. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for removing the restriction, I just posted the answer. I know the question is a bit old but I know what its like to be stuck wanting to do something and not getting help, so if I can give this person hope to get what they need done, then why not, right?

Comment: No, it's not. You can offer a bounty from the bonus rep, earn 10 rep on the site, and still not be able to answer despite your having earned 10 rep on the site (the actual criterion is 110 rep if you have the bonus, even if it says that it is to earn 10 rep on the site.)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: This is rather unintuitive, but the system is still working as designed in an instance like that. [This Meta SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238296/150283) discusses the situation. Effectively, the bounty rep is counted in full against your earned rep on the site, *even if that would result in a negative value*. So if you got the association bonus then immediately offered 50 rep bounty, the rep you had "earned" on this site would be **-49**, and you'd have to get up to 110 again (also, that 110 *is* earning 10 on the site; you "earn" 1 rep for signing up).

Comment: Now whether or not the system should be creating a "debt" of earned rep like that by dipping into the association bonus is another question entirely. I personally think it's a terribly confusing implementation.

Comment: I'm not saying that the behavior is wrong; the behavior is correct, but the **text** is wrong. The text needs to be changed to match the actual behavior.