# Can't answer protected question despite meeting reputation requirement

Tags: support

Having seen [this question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/why-cant-i-answer-a-protected-question), which is answered as, paraphrased:

> You need to have earned 10 rep *on this site*. The 100 rep association bonus does not count towards that, as explained in [this question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question).

I'm trying to self-answer [this question of my own](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25898/how-to-transfer-files-over-wifi-without-a-hotspot), which has both a bounty and protection.
As you can see from [my profile](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/17016/nit), I have earned more than 10 reputation *on this site*:

[image: Sample image]

Despite all this, scrolling to the bottom of the given question still gives me the reputation error.

> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.

Why can't I answer this question?

Comment: Try checking [this particular privilege](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) (on the right side) and see if you have it or not.

Comment: Also, [a feature request on MSE regarding this case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253573/allow-op-to-self-answer-on-their-protected-question-without-restriction-on-their)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a really unintuitive quirk of the way bounties are handled with relation to the association bonus.

Essentially, bounty reputation is always considered to be deducted from your "site" reputation. As long as you have enough total rep you can offer a bounty, but it never dips into your "bonus" reputation from associating your accounts, *even if that puts you in the negative*.

For the purposes of your reputation "on this site", Stack Exchange has calculated the following:

1. Registered an account: 1 rep earned (total earned: 1, total rep: 1)
2. Association bonus: 0 rep earned (total earned: 1, total rep: 101)
3. Question upvotes: 40 rep earned (total earned: 41, total rep: 141)
4. Suggested edits: 2 rep earned (total earned: 43, total rep: 143)
5. Bounty offered: -100 rep earned (**total earned: -57**, total rep: 43)

[This Meta SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238296/bug-cant-answer-protected-question-if-received-association-bonus-earned-10-r) contains an official explanation from one of the staff. This behavior is extremely confusing.

I have unprotected the question for you. The reason I originally applied it was because it picked up some very blatant spam off of some very unintelligent keyword search bot. If it picks up more then it may need to be protected again, but in the meantime I'll just keep an eye out for any flags on it.